# Bamboo and xCode Bot solution

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, bots, bamboo, continuous

Is there a solution to integrate an Apple Xcode Bot with Atlassian Bamboo CI ?
Searched almost all day and found nothing. 
Any ideas would be good.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently the best solution appears to be to use the Bamboo "script" task to launch xcodebuild tasks as described in the [David Hunt's comment in BAM-6149](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-6149?focusedCommentId=703328&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-703328)

However, to keep tests from failing with `Test session exited(-1) without checking in.` when run by the Bamboo remote agent, you must launch the agent from a plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ by a logged-in user. A [GUI context is required](https://github.com/facebook/xctool) in order to run iphonesimulator8.x unit tests.